# Bash script continue even previous command not ended

Tags: linux, bash

I have the command `ssh tony@mark` and want enter the password via `echo password`. I don't want use `sshpass` and as background process `ssh tony@mark &` it doesn't work. Is there any way to continue in bash script even the previous command is not ended? So the final script should work like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh tony@mark
echo -e 'MYPASSWORD\n'
```

Comment: You can redirect the stdin of your process, but it won't help in setting the password. You can also use the command parameters, but `ssh` does not allow to give the password on the comman line. `expect` could be an option as well as ssh agents, but you already discarded them. You can try to set up a publik/private key system with no password protecting the key for direct access without the need to provide a password.

Comment: In short, answering your question, you must wait for a command to finish before executing the next one or letting the command go to background and the next one runs independent of the first one.

Comment: "I have this bowl of soup and want to eat it with a knife. I don't want use spoon or drink it." Why?!?

Comment: @JohnSmith That’s not the right approach. `echo` wouldn’t send anything to the `ssh` process.

Comment: On the Apple StackExchange website, I've found following similar question, does it help you? "https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285805/how-to-ssh-in-one-line/285807"

Comment: Okay but `expect` doesn't work for me. My code is ``` #!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh tony@mark
expect "password:"
send "MYPASSWORD\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: @JohnSmith If you _can’t_ use `expect` or `sshpass` then say so. If you’ve tried to use them but failed, then describe what you did and how it didn’t work. It’s quite unclear now what kind of answer you’re looking for.

Comment: Okay but `expect` doesn't work for me. My code is ``` #!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh tony@mark
expect "password:"
send "MYPASSWORD\r"
expect eof
```  But then i can nothing do on the ssh connection. If I hit enter a blank line comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need used ssh-key. Generate a rsa keypair:`ssh-keygen`

then copy it on the server with one simple command: `ssh-copy-id userid@hostname`

you can now log in without password: `ssh userid@hostname`

---

But if you want to use a password install sshpass utility (present in apt/yum), try it:

```
sshpass -p your_password ssh user@hostname
```

---

Expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#  ./ssh.exp password 192.168.1.11 id
set pass [lrange $argv 0 0]
set server [lrange $argv 1 1]
set name [lrange $argv 2 2]

spawn ssh $name@$server
match_max 100000
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$pass\r"
send -- "\r"
interact
```

Eg:

```
# ./ssh.exp.ex password mark tony
spawn ssh tony@mark
tony@mark's password: 
Linux ubuntu-1010-server-01 2.6.35-25-generic-pae #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 19:01:46 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.10

Welcome to Ubuntu!
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Tue Mar  1 12:41:12 2011 from localhost
```

Comment: ‘*I don't want use […] `sshpass`*’

Comment: only two options: sshpass or ssh-key

Comment: maybe can help for you `expect`

Comment: OP _explicitly_ said they didn’t want to use `expect` or `sshpass`. While it’s an odd requirement, I don’t think an answer simply suggesting to use one of them is a very good answer.

Comment: I added `expect`. But ssh-key is the best option

Comment: Okay you expect script working for me. I didn't want use it because my script didn't work. I will change my question.